# How to find nearby events or tweets

Tags: mongodb, coordinates

I'm new to NoSQL databases and I'm stuck with a fairly basic query.

I have a collection of tweets in a MongoDB database, which I'm querying through both the Mongo shell and pyMongo. The documents are similar to:

```
{ loc : { lng : 40, lat : 3 },
  timestamp : 124125512,
  userid = 55 }
```

I need to find all pairs of users with events close to each other with less than 4 hours of difference. The most naive way would be:

```
db.tweets.find().forEach(function(tweet)
{
    found = db.tweets.find({ "timestamp": { "$gt" : tweet['timestamp'] - 60*60*4, 
                                            "$lt" : tweet['timestamp'] + 60*60*4},
                             "loc" : {"$near" : [ tweet['loc']['lng'], 
                                                  tweet['loc']['lat'] ], 
                                      "$maxDistance" : 500 }
                              });

    //... extract the users from those tweets...
}
```

Which of course is extremely slow (it can contain as many as a few million tweets).

I haven't been able to express this query using neither aggregation nor MapReduce. How would you do it? What is the most NoSQL-y, efficient and clear way of making this kind of query?

**EDIT:** I've kind of given up. I've been convinced by a friend that it is not going to worth it using Mongo for this. I can leverage that time restriction to avoid iterating over the whole collection and do it in a simple, more traditional iterative script. Since it is not such a huge dataset as to not fit in RAM, it's going to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$near` in conjuction with `$maxDistance` is the most recommended way

> db.collectionName.find({loc: {$near: [50, 50], $maxDistance: 5}});

For performance issues you can try creating index as mentioned below:

To create a geospatial index for GeoJSON-formatted data, use the ensureIndex() method and set the value of the location field for your collection to 2dsphere.

> db.points.ensureIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } );

For more information:

- [Index creation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/)
- [Build a 2dsphere index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/)
- [Geospatial indexes and queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#geospatial-indexes-and-queries)